# Can't inherit attributes defined inside methods of a class into another class

Tags: python, oop

I have created a banking system using classes and objects. I have observed two things while writing the code for this banking system:

1) One cannot inherit the attributes defined inside a method of one class into another class even after calling that method on an object. But, if those attributes are defined as class attributes or using the **init** function, then those attributes can be inherited.

So, in short, my conclusion is that instance attributes defined within methods of a class cannot be inherited even after calling those methods.

2) Classes with **init** function when inherited into other classes, tend to call the **init** function twice after objects for both the classes have been created.

I have attached both my codes, one showing the observation made in (1), while the other being the fixed code where I am not defining the attributes inside a method.

It would be great to know your opinions on these conclusions of mine. Below are the snapshots of my codes.

THE CODE WHERE THE ATTRIBUTE INHERITANCE FROM WITHIN A METHOD IN THE CLASS IS NOT WORKING (ATTRIBUTE ERROR):

```
from random import randint 

class User():
    def opn(self):
        self.oprn = int(input("Enter 1 to create savings or 2 to use existing one:"))
        self.name = str((input("Enter name:")))

class Bank_System(User):
    def create_savings_acc(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.name}")
        self.deposit = int(input("Enter deposit in Rs:"))
        self.acc_num = randint(10000, 99999)
        print(f"{self.name}, your new account number is {self.acc_num}")

    def existing_acc(self):
        self.decide = int(input("Press 1 to deposit or press 2 to withdraw amount:"))
        if self.decide == 1:
            print(f"You deposited amount {self.name}!")
        elif self.decide == 2:
            print(f"You withdrew amount {self.name}")
        else:
            print(f"Wrong entry, press correct number {self.name}")
            self.existing_acc()
            None


user = User()
user.opn()
bank_system = Bank_System()
if user.oprn == 1:
    bank_system.create_savings_acc()
elif user.oprn == 2:
    bank_system.existing_acc()
else:
    print("Wrong Entry")
```

The error message for this code is:

```
Enter 1 to create savings or 2 to use existing one:1
Enter name: MNR


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d72cc4996dbe> in <module>
     29 bank_system = Bank_System()
     30 if user.oprn == 1:
---> 31     bank_system.create_savings_acc()
     32 elif user.oprn == 2:
     33     bank_system.existing_acc()

<ipython-input-6-d72cc4996dbe> in create_savings_acc(self)
      8 class Bank_System(User):
      9     def create_savings_acc(self):
---> 10         print(f"Hi {self.name}")
     11         self.deposit = int(input("Enter deposit in Rs:"))
     12         self.acc_num = randint(10000, 99999)

AttributeError: 'Bank_System' object has no attribute 'name'
```

The fixed code is:

```
from random import randint 

class User():
    oprn = int(input("Enter 1 to create savings or 2 to use existing one:"))
    name = str((input("Enter name:")))

class Bank_System(User):
    def create_savings_acc(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.name}")
        self.deposit = int(input("Enter deposit in Rs:"))
        self.acc_num = randint(10000, 99999)
        print(f"{self.name}, your new account number is {self.acc_num}")

    def existing_acc(self):
        self.decide = int(input("Press 1 to deposit or press 2 to withdraw amount:"))
        if self.decide == 1:
            print(f"You deposited amount {self.name}!")
        elif self.decide == 2:
            print(f"You withdrew amount {self.name}")
        else:
            print(f"Wrong entry, press correct number {self.name}")
            self.existing_acc()
            None


user = User()
bank_system = Bank_System()
if user.oprn == 1:
    bank_system.create_savings_acc()
elif user.oprn == 2:
    bank_system.existing_acc()
else:
    print("Wrong Entry")
```

Please let me know if my conclusion is correct about the method attributes not being able to be inherited. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You never call `bank_system.opn()`, so you never add those attributes.

Comment: What are you expecting `self.name` to be for `bank_system`? There's no relationship between the `bank_system` and `user` instances.

Comment: There is no distinction between attributes created by `__init__` or other methods, you simply **never called `.opn`** Also, your design doesn't make sense. A bank system isn't a user.

Comment: The bank system and user are different objects for which I defined separate classes. My idea was to inherit the user attributes (which is the user's name and the user's input) into the bank system. But, I understand what your saying. Instead of user.opn(), I added bank_system.opn(). Now, the code works correctly. Thank you!